# DashDB to MySQL Migration

Tags: mysql, ibm-cloud, dashdb

Does anyone know an efficient way to migrate from **DashDB to MySQL** ? I have a database schema on DashDB which contains *n number of* tables and I wanted to migrate to MySQL.

The only way I can think of is exporting each table to CSV and then import it in MySQL but I am sure there is a better way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: May be you can make use of [IBM DataWorks](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/dataworks/) on Bluemix?

Answer (score 0):

The [IBM DataWorks](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/dataworks/) service on Bluemix is designed for this exact purpose. Here is a screenshot of what the interface looks like:

[image: Data Transfer Screenshot]

After [creating a free Bluemix account](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/registration/), find the service in the [catalog](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/dataworks/) and create an instance of it. You can try the service under the 'starter' level plan for free. A getting started guide can be found in the [Bluemix Docs.](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/dataworks1/index.html#dataworks)

Hope this helps

Comment: interesting, but I tired the "Refine and Copy" task and I get this error : `Connections to MySQL Community Server are not supported. Please contact MySQL to obtain a MySQL Enterprise or Commercial version. `

Comment: Okay. Not sure why that is the case. The supported DBs are here, which includes MySQL without any other designation: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/dataworks1/index-gentopic2.html#task_d4j_q1r_np

Comment: I think you are referring to [this project](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1507dataworks1-bluemix-trs/index.html I ) I tried to deploy it but I get this error `Error creating the activity:
Exception thrown by application class 'org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage:116'` after following all the instructions and bounding the datawork

Comment: I reached out to the author of the referenced developerWorks article. He said that you seem to be trying to migrate from dashDB to MySQL while the dashDB source and the MySQL target is not supported by the DataWorks app. The table of supported combinations is at https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/dataworks1/index-gentopic2.html#t_data_load_create